# scriptResourceHandler

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Does anyone know much about the Asp.Net webconfig element ?
I'm looking at it because I'm implementing an MS Ajax updatepanel in an existing site, 
and after doing some looking around, on the web I'm not finding a lot of info about it.

And to avoid the flood of replies telling me how inefficient the update panel is, and that it's not actually providing any benefit etc. etc. I know! Let's say I've got my reasons for using it and leave it at that.

I guess my main question is;, will setting enableCompression="true" and enableCaching="true" help the performace of my update panel in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the traversing of the DOM that is actually happening with an update panel it's generally not the content that is hindering performance.. it is the PC/Browser.

I know this is exactly what you aren't looking for but unless your panel contains a significant amount of data then compression and caching isn't going to help you terribly.

Answer (score 0):

I took this from the scriptresourcehandler documentation:
By default, the ScriptResourceHandler class compresses and caches embedded script files for Internet Explorer 7.

So I don't think you'll see any difference if you set enableCompression/enableCaching true because it's already happening if you're using IE7.